# Jquery add different style to multiple tags with same class?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to add a class to multiple div elements with same class, but not add the same class for all.
(all the div elements are created with jquery, not manually in html so i don't know if the value inside the div will be "Yes" or "No", it's "random")
Example 
html:

```
<div class = "flag"> Yes </div>
<div class = "flag"> No </div>
<div class = "flag"> Yes </div>
<div class = "flag"> Yes </div>
<div class = "flag"> No </div>
```

css:

```
.yes{
   color : green;
}

.no{
   color : red;
}
```

I want to apply .yes for div with "Yes" and .no for div with "no".
i tried this but not working, or it apply .yes for all div:

```
$(".flag").each(function(){ 
            if($(".flag").text() == "yes"){
                $(".flag").addClass("yes");
            }else{
                $(".flag").addClass("no");
            }
        });
```

Comment: try change `if($(".flag").text()` to `if($(this).text()`

Comment: it apply .yes to all div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of issues here.

- You select every `.flag` element when you add the classes, not the one in the loop iteration. Use the `this` keyword to fix that.
- The content is `Yes`, not `yes`, and JS is case sensitive.
- The content also contains whitespace which needs to be removed before the comparison. You can use `trim()` for that.

```js
$(".flag").each(function() {
  if ($(this).text().trim() == "Yes") {
    $(this).addClass("yes");
  } else {
    $(this).addClass("no");
  }
});
```

```css
.yes { color: green; }
.no { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flag"> Yes </div>
<div class="flag"> No </div>
<div class="flag"> Yes </div>
<div class="flag"> Yes </div>
<div class="flag"> No </div>
```

However you can achieve this much more simply by using an implicit loop, by providing a function to `addClass()` and a ternary expression:

```js
$(".flag").addClass(function() {
  return $(this).text().trim() == "Yes" ? 'yes' : 'no';
});
```

```css
.yes { color: green; }
.no { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flag"> Yes </div>
<div class="flag"> No </div>
<div class="flag"> Yes </div>
<div class="flag"> Yes </div>
<div class="flag"> No </div>
```